# Search for a specific word in multiple csv files

Tags: python, string, csv, search

I am new to python and have a task at hand. I have multiple csv files in a folder and need to find a particular word in those files. I then need the file name. Any coder in python who can give me some guidance?

Comment: Can you kindly show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that:

```
from glob import glob
text = 'test'
for filename in glob('*.csv'):
    with open(filename) as input_file:
        if text in input_file.read():
            print(f'{text} was found in file {filename}')
```

Edit: Moved it into a function ->

```
from glob import glob


def find_files_with_text(pathname, value):
    files_containing_value = []
    for filename in glob(pathname):
        with open(filename) as input_file:
            if value in input_file.read():
                files_containing_value.append(filename)
    return files_containing_value


path = './*.txt'
text = 'test'

print(find_files_with_text(path, text))
```

Comment: This would work based on the users question. May even be useful to create a function, and return `filename` from within the loop when `text` is found.

Comment: @LiamFiddler what would be the code for that?

Comment: Also, is there any way I can ask it to parse through a folder of csv files rather than a single csv file once at a time?

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a function. I'm not sure how you envision a solution that avoids opening individual files one by one. Are you thinking of threads running in parallel? A distributed file system, like hdfs, might be useful for that (?)